# Adding description to submit dialog called from p4vc

Tags: perforce, p4v

In my script, which submits some changes to perforce, I would like to add an interactive mode. The workflow should be as follow:

1. the script changes some files which are checked out in the default change list.
2. the script calls `p4vc submit`, so the user can inspect the changes and submit them as they are or make some minor changes.

However, the description of the submit form is empty and I would like to populate it from the script, so the user don't have to write it by hand.

Is it possible to pass a default description of the change list using **p4vc**?  I could not find this information in the documentation, which is kept pretty short.

PS: I would like to avoid creating a new change list with proper description and then submit it - because if the user cancels the operation, the files would be in this change list, but I would like to keep them in the default list in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your principal question is the one contained in your 'P.S.'.

That is, you're trying to avoid leaving the files opened in a numbered pending changelist if the user decides not to perform the submit at this time.

After your script has invoked `p4vc submit`, your script could find out if the user halted the submit operation (by running `p4 opened` to see that the files were not submitted), and then could use `p4 reopen` to move them back into the default changelist, and `p4 change -d` to delete the unwanted pending numbered changelist.

Comment: Thank, that works, but is a little bit brittle - there are too many steps to my liking. So there is no way to achieve it by using p4vc?

Comment: One more problem I have: p4vc returns directly after the calling of the submit-dialog and not after the user is done with it. Do you know a way to let the call to p4vc to wait until the user is done and return afterwards?

Comment: Yuck. I was a little bit worried about that "returns early" possibility. Sadly, I have very little experience with `p4vc`.